# Swap (toggle) a CSS property with data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, swap, custom-data-attribute, value-of-css-property

I have an element with defined "background-color" and with another color value in a custom "data" attribute.

What I need to do, on click, is to swap those two values (toggle them every time a button is clicked).

ISSUE: The values do swap once with my code and then something gets stuck and the swap isn't working anymore.

Here's the code:

```
<span class="button" title="Switch background color"></span>

<div class="targeted-element" style="background-color: #dedede;" data-new-color="rgba(14,22,33,1)"></div>

<script>
$( 'span.button' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( '.targeted-element' ).each(function() {
        var $back_color = $( this ).css( 'background-color' );
        var $new_color = $( this ).data( 'new-color' );
        $( this ).css( 'background-color', $new_color );
        $( this ).attr( 'data-new-color', $back_color );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note, I also tried $( this ).data( 'new-color', $back_color ); first ( instead of $( this ).attr( 'data-new-color', $back_color ); ) but that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my code works. After I posted the quetion I went back, refreshed and it worked.

I always empty cache and hard reload but apparently .js files sometimes don't update even on that, which caused my issue even though I refreshed my page ~20 times.